# Ordenação de matriz de strings alocada dinamicamente em C (com qsort)

Tags: c, matriz, classificação, quicksort

Estou tendo problemas pra ordenar uma matriz de strings alocada dinamicamente. Sempre usei `qsort()` pra ordenar vetores e matrizes (mas só com alocação estática). Agora fui tentar ordenar uma matriz dinâmica e não dá certo, ele simplesmente não ordena. Fiz no mesmo código uma matriz dinâmica e outra estática, a estática ele ordena e a dinâmica não. O que estou fazendo de errado?

A ordenação em si, a função de comparação e a chamada do `qsort()`, eu peguei de um material que achei na internet, mas a alocação usada é estática. Não acho nada sobre ordenação de matrizes dinâmicas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp (const void *, const void *);

int main () {

    char **nomes_din, nomes_est[5][50];

    // alocacao da matriz 
    nomes_din = (char**)malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        nomes_din[i] = (char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    }

    // leitura dos nomes
    printf("Matriz dinamica:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        scanf("%s", nomes_din[i]);
    }
    printf("Matriz estatica:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        scanf("%s", nomes_est[i]);
    }

    // ordenacao
    qsort((void*)nomes_din, 5, sizeof(nomes_din[0]), comp);
    qsort((void*)nomes_est, 5, sizeof(nomes_est[0]), comp);

    // impressao dos nomes ordenados
    printf("\n");
    printf("Matriz dinamica ordenada:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", nomes_din[i]);
    }
    printf("Matriz estatica ordenada:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", nomes_est[i]);
    }

    // liberacao da memoria 
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        free(nomes_din[i]);
    }
    free(nomes_din);

    return 0;

}

int comp (const void *a, const void *b) {

    return (strcmp((char *) a, (char *) b));

}
```

Comment: Está construindo errado a tal "matriz dinâmica" se pretende usar `qsort()`. Insira `printf("comp(%s,%s)\n",(const char*)a,(const char*)b); `   em `comp()` antes do return e vai entender. Ou muda a construção ou o sort.
nunca escreva um programa interativo até poder evitar. Só perde tempo.

Answer (score 1):

`qsort()` nada sabe nada sobre matrizes estáticas ou dinâmicas. Não há como pesquisar algo assim. `qsort()`apenas espera um endereço de uma área de memória contínua a ser dividida em partes de tamanho fixo, e uma noção de ordem, a ser dada pela função de comparação

```
void qsort(
   void *base,
   size_t number,
   size_t width,
   int ( *compare )(const void *, const void *)
);
```

como descrita na [documentação aqui por exemplo](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/qsort?view=msvc-170).

Não pode usar a mesma função se construiu a tal área de modo totalmente diferente. Eis as duas que usou:

```
    char **nomes_din, nomes_est[5][50];
```

E são bem diferentes... Evite declarar mais de uma variável por linha. É grátis. E nunca deixe ponteiros sem inicializar, por uma linha que seja. Prefira

```
    char**    nomes_din == NULL;
    char      nomes_est[5][50];
```

E entenda que está declarando em `C` `nomes_din` e o tipo de `nomes_din` é `char**` isso implica em `*nomes_din` ser `char*` E assim `**nomes_din` é um `char`, uma letrinha. Para o compilador tanto faz mas para quem está lendo e em especial aprendendo é melhor usar a formatação a seu favor.

### Usando a função de comparação correta

Do modo como construiu uma função assim faria o serviço:

```
int comp_d(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return strcmp( *( (const char**) a), *( (const char**) b) );
}
```

porque está classificando 5 ponteiros. Nada mais. Na função de comparação o programa vê para onde eles apontam e extrai a informação de ordem. Seria como classificar um vetor de endereços pela data de cadastro neles na lista: a função de comparação é que resolve, já que a ordem nem vem dos dados como estão no vetor. Imagino que tenha entendido a analogia.

### um exemplo mudando a função

#### saída

```
    Matriz dinamica:

        "5 - dinamica"
        "4 - dinamica"
        "3 - dinamica"
        "2 - dinamica"
        "1 - dinamica"

    qsort():

    Matriz dinamica ordenada:

        "1 - dinamica"
        "2 - dinamica"
        "3 - dinamica"
        "4 - dinamica"
        "5 - dinamica"
```

#### O código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int comp_d(const void*, const void*);

int main(void)
{
    // alocacao da matriz
    printf("    Matriz dinamica:\n\n");
    char** nomes_din = (char**)malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        nomes_din[i] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(nomes_din[i], "  - dinamica");
        nomes_din[i][0] = '5' - i;
        printf("\t\"%s\"\n", nomes_din[i]);
    }

    printf("\n    qsort():\n");
    qsort(nomes_din, 5, sizeof(char*), comp_d);

    printf("\n    Matriz dinamica ordenada:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("\t\"%s\"\n", nomes_din[i]);

    // liberacao da memoria
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) free(nomes_din[i]);
    free(nomes_din);
    return 0;
}

int comp_d(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return strcmp( *( (const char**) a), *( (const char**) b) );
}
```

### Alocando e construindo a matriz do mesmo modo que a estática

Se a matriz estática era `char[5][50] então deve alocar uma igual por exemplo assim

```
    // alocacao da matriz
    char(*nomes_din)[5][50] = malloc(5 * 50 * sizeof(char));
```

E aí sim podera usar a mesma função `comp()`

### um exemplo alocando a área do mesmo modo

```
    Matriz dinamica:

        "5 - dinamica"
        "4 - dinamica"
        "3 - dinamica"
        "2 - dinamica"
        "1 - dinamica"

    qsort():

    Matriz dinamica ordenada:

        "1 - dinamica"
        "2 - dinamica"
        "3 - dinamica"
        "4 - dinamica"
        "5 - dinamica"
```

#### código usando a mesma `comp()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int comp(const void*, const void*);

int main(void)
{
    // alocacao da matriz
    char(*nomes_din)[5][50] = malloc(5 * 50 * sizeof(char));

    printf("    Matriz dinamica:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        strcpy((*nomes_din)[i], "  - dinamica");
        (*nomes_din)[i][0] = '5' - i;
        printf("\t\"%s\"\n", (*nomes_din)[i]);
    }

    printf("\n    qsort():\n");
    qsort((void*) nomes_din, 5, sizeof((*nomes_din)[0]), comp);

    printf("\n    Matriz dinamica ordenada:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("\t\"%s\"\n", (*nomes_din)[i]);

    // liberacao da memoria
    free(nomes_din);
    return 0;
}

int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return (strcmp((char*)a, (char*)b));
}
```

#### nunca escreva um programa interativo

Só perde tempo fazendo isso. Use um gerador, constantes, um prato de cerâmica, qualquer coisa que permita rodar imediatamente o programa sem ter que ficar esperando e inventando e digitando strings toda vez que for testar. Veja como eu escrevi nos exemplos, gerando as strings já numeradas e em ordem inversa...

> Escrevi os dois exemplos porque há uma tendência por parte dos
> iniciantes em achar que `char[][]` e `char**` são a mesma coisa. E os
> livros também nao gastam muito tempo com isso

Comment: @AugustoVasques é, aquilo não acrescentava nada afinal e retirei. Bom ter apontado. Quanto a usar cppReference não vejo vantagem aqui. Imagino que não tenha visto a documentação que  citei: o texto lá é bem melhor para o nível dessa questão e o exemplo é muito melhor que o que está em cppReference porque trata exatamente dessa pergunta. O que eu escrevi só é melhor porque mostra o outro lado: como alocar a área de modo a poder usar a mesma função de comparação. cppReference em geral tem um texto mais a la standard, mais formal que o esperado por um iniciante. E não tem o botão copy :)

Comment: eu coloquei as dimensões 5 e 50 só pra testar, mas elas são desconhecidas até o usuário digitar o tamanho desejado; então declarando do jeito que você mostrou, ficaria char(*nomes_din)[N][50] = malloc(N * 50 * sizeof(char)); mas me ensinaram que não é uma boa prática declarar assim (com o N entre colchetes)

Comment: não foi isso que eu mostrei no exemplo. E aquela é a maneira comum de declarar isso. Mais ainda, é a maneira usada pelo sistema operacional,. Não por acaso TODO programa C por exemplo recebe um `char**` ou `char*[]` em `argv`.